# Why does --date= affect the %gd git log format?

Tags: git, git-log, git-stash

```
$ git stash list --format="%gd, %cd"
stash@{0}, Fri Sep 22 11:40:25 2017 +0100
stash@{1}, Mon Sep 18 16:12:11 2017 +0100
```

Stash id's and long format dates. If I try to get short dates:

```
$ git stash list --format="%gd, %cd" --date=short
stash@{2017-09-22}, 2017-09-22
stash@{2017-09-18}, 2017-09-18
```

Why did the stash id also change into a date? `%cd` is [documented](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) to respect `--date=`, but not `%gd` (and it's not supposed to show a date anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> %gD: reflog selector, e.g., refs/stash@{1} or refs/stash@{2 minutes
> ago}; **the format follows the rules described for the -g option**.
> The portion before the @ is the refname as given on the command line
> (so git log -g refs/heads/master would yield refs/heads/master@{0}).
>
> %gd: shortened reflog selector; **same as %gD**, but the refname portion
> is shortened for human readability (so refs/heads/master becomes just
> master).

So `%gd` is same as `%gD` and `%gD`'s format follows the rules of `-g`. Let's take a look at `-g`.

> -g
>
> --walk-reflogs
>
> Instead of walking the commit ancestry chain, walk reflog entries from the most recent one to older ones. When this
> option is used you cannot specify commits to exclude (that is,
> ^commit, commit1..commit2, and commit1...commit2 notations cannot be
> used).
>
> With --pretty format other than oneline (for obvious reasons), this
> causes the output to have two extra lines of information taken from
> the reflog. The reflog designator in the output may be shown as
> ref@{Nth} (where Nth is the reverse-chronological index in the reflog)
> or as ref@{timestamp} (with the timestamp for that entry), depending
> on a few rules:
>
> If the starting point is specified as ref@{Nth}, show the index
> format.
>
> If the starting point was specified as ref@{now}, show the timestamp
> format.
>
> **If neither was used, but --date was given on the command line, show**
> **the timestamp in the format requested by --date.**
>
> Otherwise, show the index format.

So it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! Then I can get what I want with `git stash list --format="%gd, %cd" --date=short stash@{0}`